How to set the stack and managed user identity of azure app service via powershell
I'm trying to set the stack to .NET v4.8 and specify a managed user identity via powershell (in a runbook), but not getting anywhere.
I have tried:
Set-AzWebApp -Name $webApp.Name -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroupName -SiteConfig @{"NetFrameworkVersion" = "v4.0"}
Set-AzWebApp -Name $webApp.Name -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroupName -AppSettings @{"AssignIdentity" = $identity.Id}
and all kinds of variations.  Can anyone help me out here please?  thank you much

specify a managed user identity You want to enable Identity ? or you are looking for any particular setting.Please confirm.

Updateing the runtime using powershell is not possible.Even if you update and run the command it will show as v4.0 itself.Refer GitHub and MSDoc

$rgName = ""
$appName = ""

## update config
$appSettings = @{}
$appSettings['NetFrameworkVersion'] = 'v4.0'
Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rgName  -Name $appName -AppSettings $appSettings


## I also find someone using below 

$rgName = ''
$webappName = ''
$servicePlanName = ''

New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $webappName -AppServicePlan $servicePlanName
##
$config = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName $webappName -ApiVersion 2018-02-01
$config.Properties.linuxFxVersion = "DOTNETCORE|9.0"
$config | Set-AzResource -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force




Thank you for this.  I need to assign a user assigned managed identity, not a system assigned.  I ran the above and it seems to do something but the portal still reflects no stack.  odd.  any ideas?
thank you

PS /home/ext-barry> $appSettings = @{}
PS /home/ext-barry> $appSettings['NetFrameworkVersion'] = 'v4.0'
PS /home/ext-barry> Set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroupName  -Name $WebAppName -AppSettings $appSettings

If I can't set the runtime after creation, can I set it during creation?  i have:
Create the Web App in the specified App Service Plan and Resource Group
$webApp = New-AzWebApp     -ResourceGroupName $WebAppResourceGroupName
-Name  $WebAppName     -Location  $WebAppLocation
-AppServicePlan $appServicePlan.Id     -AseName $ASEName
-AseResourceGroupName $AppServiceEnvironmentResourceGroupName
How can I set it to .net?  how about managed user identity?  than kyou

@Hi barraySDCA, 1. Q1 as I said in preivous answer, Documents reference showing user-managed identiy not support for azure web app right now, but I have just configu in azure portal, the azure web app can be set with user managed identity, but i can not found a command to achieve it. Q2. I am also not managed to find a command to create a new webapp with runtime specifing. all commnads are re-set after the webapp resource existing. but az web create using azure-cli can achieve the goal.

To create a new App Service and add a user-assigned identity to it, I use this command in PowerShell :
$AppService = az webapp create --name $AppServiceName_win `
                               --plan $AppServicePlan_win `
                               -g $rgname `
                               --runtime 'ASPNET:V4.8' `
                               --assign-identity $identityId `
                               | ConvertFrom-Json

Run this command to list all available runtimes:
az webapp list-runtimes

I did a more in-depth post about creating and App Services here https://nestenius.se/2024/08/27/deploy-a-container-to-azure-app-services-using-azure-cli-and-user-assigned-managed-identity/
